# Is subspace of a vector space a quotient space?

Tags: vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Reasoning:

1. Given a vector space V and a subspace W of V.
2. "x≡y (mod W) if x-y∈W" defines **equivalence relation**.
3. **equivalence relation** partitions V into **equivalence classes**.
4. **equivalence classes** is called **cosets** of W in V.
5. Define the **quotient space** V/W, whose elements are **cosets** of W in V.

My question:

If x & y ∈ W, x-y∈W. So it seems **W⊆quotient space** since W is a coset of itself. 
   True? If yes, why V/W?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an element of the quotient space that has the same members as $W$, so $W$ is an *element* of $V/W$, but no, $W$ is not a *subset* of the quotient space. A subset of the quotient space would be a collection whose members are equivalence classes.

You are right when you say that $W$ is a coset of itself though, and that is why $W$ is an element of $V/W$.

Comment: Just ask a short question: to V/W, what does / mean? exclusion?

Comment: @sleevechen $/$ merely indicates that this is a quotient space. In general $/$ is used to denote a quotient structure, where the object on the left is the base structure and the object on the right is what cosets are being formed from. Sometimes an equivalence relation will appear on the right when it is more convenient to think in terms of equivalence classes instead of cosets. The notation is sometimes read as "$V$ mod $W$."